# Handling variable scope in a python script

Tags: python

I am learning to code in Python.
I am creating a program that will perform unit conversions, however I have been stuck on this error for a good while:

> NameError: name 'ini' is not defined

Here is the code:

```py
a = ("Distance")
b = ("Time")
c = ("Volume")
d = ("Temp")
e = ("Weight")

def conversion_type(first):
    if first == ("Distance"):
        ini = input("How great a distance am I converting?\n")
    elif first == ("Time"):
        ini = input("How much time am I converting?\n")
    elif first == ("Volume"):
        ini = input("How great a volume am I converting?\n")
    elif first == ("Temp"):
        ini = input("How many degrees am I converting?\n")
    elif first == ("Weight"):
        ini = input("How much weight am I converting?\n")
    else:
        print("That not was an afformentioned dimension you dolt.")

def variable_type_converter(ini):
    ini = float(ini)

print ("\n    Welcome to the Convert-O-Matic\n==============================\n")
print ("I support the following dimensions:\n")
print ("%s, %s, %s, %s, and %s," % (a,b,c,d,e))
first = input("What kind of conversion would you like to do?\n")
conversion_type(first)
variable_type_converter(ini)
print("==========================================")
```

Comment: Uh oh!, code screenshots make me sad.

Comment: I apologize, the insert code feature was spitting out garbage

Comment: @John, try again. We can always fix the formatting, especially if you leave the screenshot in there for verification (and we'll end up deleting the screenshot once the code is verified).

Comment: @JohnStivers Select the pasted code and then either do CTRL-k or hit the `{}` button.

Comment: I came back around and typed in the code from your screenshot. I also updated my answer to note one of your functions does nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ini` is not declared in the global scope, only inside of functions (it is used in `conversion_type()` and therefore implicitly declared there, and it is an argument to `variable_type_converter()`). But since it was not declared in the global scope, it does not exist there. If you want to set the value of `ini` in `conversion_type()` and have the value be usable elsewhere, declare a value for `ini` somewhere before you call `conversion_type()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/2449905) has a good summary of Python's scoping rules.

**Update:** As MadWombat points out in comments, your `variable_type_converter()` function doesn't do anything. It takes one argument, called `ini`, it casts it as float and reassigns back to `ini`, but then it doesn't return a value. So when the `variable_type_converter()` function exits, the value is discarded and and the float cast is never used.

Comment: This is a good answer. I would like to add, that by doing ini = float(ini) you are not actually converting anything. You need to return a value and assign the function result outside of the function.
def to_float(ini):
    return float(ini)

ini = to_float(ini)

Answer (score 1):

When defining your variables you should use `a = "Distance"`. You should also check the conversion type using `first == "Distance"`

`ini` is not defined, is occurring because the function `conversion_type(first)` is returning a value that is not stored. Try:

```
# get conversion type 
conversion_type_chosen = conversion_type(first)

# calculate value
converted_value = variable_type_convertor(conversion_type_chosen)

# print result
print "result: {}".format(converted_value)
```